# Adding conditional pipe() action inside merge()

Tags: javascript, rxjs

### Case

Using `merge()` to merge 3 sources of the data on the page:

```
merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page, this.searchQuery$)
      .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(() => {
```

### Problem

`sort` and `paginator` are *instant* source (user clicks on the control and instantly changes the value. While `searchQuery` is generated by the text input field.

I would like to add `debounceTime(500)` but only for the `searchQuery$` while **keeping other 2 sources included**.

How does one achieve this with RxJs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add operators in a `pipe` to any Observable.

```
merge(
  this.sort.sortChange, 
  this.paginator.page, 
  this.searchQuery$.pipe(debounceTime(500))
)
```